# Rails - How to output attributes from polymorphic associations in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, polymorphic-associations

so I currently have two models setup, a Student model and a User (devise) model. Both are associated using polymorph (member). Here is what I currently have:

Student.rb

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :user, as: :member, :inverse_of => :member
    belongs_to :my_class 
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member, polymorphic: true, :inverse_of => :user
end
```

schema.rb is something like this

```
  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "full_name"
    t.string   "phone_number"
    t.integer  "member_id"
    t.string   "member_type"
    t.date     "dob"
  end



create_table "students", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "code"
    #other student related attributes
  end
```

My question is: how do I output the 'code' attribute from Student in my view? I realize that I can do something like `<%= current_user.member_id %>` and match it with the Student model, but as far as I know, both models (User and Student) are only figuratively linked through member? (ie there is nothing to match them with).

Any suggestions/pointers on how to proceed from here? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you should put:

```
<%= current_user.member.code %>
```

Because in your database you have `member_id` AND `member_type`, rails knows what model member is (that is, if you created the object association correctly).